# how to get rid of firebase cert causing an error on my domain?

Tags: wordpress, firebase, firebase-hosting

Anyone familiar with firebase, or just wordpress tech in general, willing to help me with an error I created?

Experimented with adding firebase to one of my sites, mainly trying to get a good 301 redirect going. Didn't pan out, tried deleting everything but for a while now I get this error when trying to load my domain.

I tried reinstalling a new ssl cert in my host, but that didnt do anything. Dunno where else to look to delete or edit files.

Your connection is not private

This server could not prove that it is kylebeckerconstruction.com; its security certificate is from firebaseapp.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the DNS records for your domain, as it appears they are likely still pointing to Firebase. You can use the `dig` tool (Linux/macOS) for this:

```
dig +short mydomain.com
```

If the resulting records look like:

```
151.101.65.195
151.101.1.195
```

then you are still pointed at Firebase Hosting and should change your DNS records with your domain provider.

Comment: Hey I really appreciate the response! 

Yeah those ip addies come up along with my hosts its weird. 

I was on chat support with my hosting provider trying to get this sorted and he sent me a link to some dns lookup and said 'the 194... are our ip but the 151... are not'

Comment: I double checked again but my registrar is only showing the 2 nameservers that I put in there that go to my host. I have no idea where else to look or how to disconnect firebase?

It must be in some file in my wordpress folders?

https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/kylebeckerconstruction.com

Dallas TX, United States
Speakeasy
151.101.1.195
151.101.65.195
194.1.147.68
194.1.147.79

Comment: Looks like you're using WPX judging by your NS servers. [This article](https://kb.wpx.net/how-to-setup-dns-records-for-the-most-common-3rd-party-services-google-apps-zoho-office-365/) might help. You need to edit the DNS records and remove the two Firebase Hosting ones. Right now your domain has 4 A records, 2 from Firebase Hosting and 2 from somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just deleted the 2 a records for firebase...works fine now thank you again for real.